# How to record voice using react native web?

Tags: react-native, react-native-web

Is there a way to record and play audio using react native web? I have been looking for some resources but I wasn't able to find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the following npm library:

https://github.com/jsierles/react-native-audio

A simple example how to use this module.

```
import {AudioRecorder, AudioUtils} from 'react-native-audio';
let audioPath = AudioUtils.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test.aac';

AudioRecorder.prepareRecordingAtPath(audioPath, {
  SampleRate: 22050,
  Channels: 1,
  AudioQuality: "Low",
  AudioEncoding: "aac"
});
```

In order to play back sound you could then use the following:

https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound